# XSL as javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I searched and tried various solutions (using xsl:variable for e.g.), but none worked.

Here is my case. This works, but I would like to pass xsl_value-of as argument to alert():

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('text')"><xsl:value-of select="@naziv" /></a>
```

So it would be something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('{<xsl:value-of select="@naziv" />}')"><xsl:value-of select="@naziv" /></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an attribute value template i.e.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('{@naziv}');"><xsl:value-of select="@naziv"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, far more elegant solution!